# Trying to pass results of database query between two C# ASP.NET pages using WebMatrix

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, webmatrix

I am using Microsoft WebMatrix to create a basic web app. To speed up the development process I decided to use the 'Starter Site' that is supplied through the WebMatrix program.

On my site I am experiencing a display issue wherein the table that I am displaying on one of my pages is simply too wide (and the user needs to scroll a significant amount to the right of the browser window).

The table is being populated from a DB query, and I think that the best way to get around the display issue is to employ an IFrame. However as the IFrame cannot take the table directly, but instead must be 'populated' by an additional web page I now must pass the results of my database query between pages in my application.

I have tried doing this using the Session variable, however this only appears to hold key, value pairs, whereas in reality the results of my database query more closely resemble an array.

At the top of my page I make the variable declaration for the database query as follows -

```
var db = Database.Open("AU");
var resultSetH = db.Query("SELECT 1;");
```

(I have simplified above)

I now need to pass the 'resultSetH' variable between (C#) asp pages (within WebMatrix).

How can I go about my intended task? Is this even possible without using MVC?

Comment: You tagged this as [ASP Classic](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/asp-classic/info). That is distinctly different from [ASP.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/asp.net/info). You should update your tags to make it clear what you're using.

Answer (score 1):

No, no, NO! Using an iframe just because you can't fit some data on your screen is not a good solution. iframes often create additional problems. Instead, just use a div with a fixed width and [scroll bars](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp).

```
<div style="overflow: auto; width: 500px">Your really long data here.</div>
```

And Session holds key value pairs, but the value can be any object. However, Session is a poor choice for passing data between pages because Session isn't tied to any particular page, which makes it difficult to handle a situation with multiple windows/tabs open on the same session and can end up confusing your users or breaking your application. Instead, you can pass data to a new page by providing query string parameters. Not that I'm reccomending that in this case since embedding another page in an iframe would be a bad idea, but I just wanted to make it clear that session can store anything that's serializable.